# Get recursive depth for every row

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

I have the following db table

[image]

82 is the parent of 84. 24 is the parent of 82 and 83. In php I have a method to fetch rows by uid.

```
public function fetchByUid($uid){
    //code
}
```

This would retrieve the 7th and 6th value from the table. Now I want to fetch not only the rows where uid is equal but also the rows where the parent is the child of uid. E.g. 82 is a parent of 84 but also a child of 24.

So I came up with some recursion.

```
public function fetchByUidRec($uid, $data, $counter){
    //set of rows by uid
    $db_resultSet;

    foreach($db_resultSet as $row){
        $entry = array();
        $entry['id'] = $row->id;
        $entry['uid'] = $row->uid;
        $entry['rid'] = $row->rid;
        $entry['layer'] = $counter;
        $data [] = $entry;

        //now I want to do the same on the child
        $data [] = fetchByUidRec($row->rid, $data, $counter = $counter + 1)
    }

    return $data;
}

public function getchByUid($uid){
   $data = array();
   $counter = 0;

   return fetchByUidRec($uid, $data, $counter)
}
```

But that does not work at all :( I want to store the current recrusion depth in $data['layer']

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly:

```
$rows = array
(
    0 => array('id' => 8, 'uid' => 82, 'rid' => 84),
    1 => array('id' => 7, 'uid' => 24, 'rid' => 82),
    2 => array('id' => 6, 'uid' => 24, 'rid' => 83),
);

function fetchByUidRec($uid, $counter = 0)
{
    global $rows;

    // or in your case
    // $rows = SELECT FROM table WHERE uid = $uid;

    $data = array();

    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        if ($row['uid'] == $uid)
        {
            $data[] = array_merge($row, array('layer' => $counter));
            $data = array_merge($data, fetchByUidRec($row['rid'], $counter++));
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

---

**Example**:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r(fetchByUidRec(24));
echo '</pre>';
```

---

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [uid] => 24
            [rid] => 82
            [layer] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [uid] => 82
            [rid] => 84
            [layer] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [uid] => 24
            [rid] => 83
            [layer] => 1
        )
)
```

Comment: thanks, but as you can see in my code I dont retrieve the entire rows from the table but only those that match the uid, this is indicated by  $db_resultSet....; For every child of the parent I again make a db query (which would be layer 1) now for all childs of uid and so on...

Comment: @ArtWorkAD: That's irrelevant to your problem I think, I just adapted your code to provide a fully workable example. I suggest you fix the typos and bugs on your code and maybe also provide the code for the `fetchByUid` / `getchByUid` methods. Your question is somewhat confusing as it is.

Comment: @ArtWorkAD: Check the comment in my code, wouldn't that do it?